# К вопросу о свойствах русского языка (10)

Tags: орфография

Небуквенный орфографический символ "-" используется при написании наименований городов (например, пишут "Камень-на-Оби" и не пишут "КаменьнаОби", пишут "Санкт-Петербург" и не пишут "СанктПетербург").

Предположим, я предложу, чтобы русские писали наименование каждого города в соответствии с рекомендациями Русского географического общества (РГО), утверждёнными на референдуме жителей этого города, которые имеют право голоса.

**Вопрос:** Противоречит ли указанное предложение хотя бы одному свойству русского языка?

P.S.

1. Сколько подписей в защиту дефиса собрано stopkran'ом?
2. Если в РФ появится передвижной населённый пункт по имени "Бордель-на-Колёсах", тогда я не буду возражать, чтобы названный пункт переехал из "дикой" России на "цивилизованный" Запад вместе с дефисами.

Comment: 15 подписей

Comment: В Сочи скоро грядут Олимпийские Игры. Как правильно : Краснополянский или Красно-Полянский, и в чем, собственно, разница?? Какие тут особенные свойства языка проявляются, кроме естественной вариативности графического оформления. Южноамериканская Северо-Западная ж/д магистраль, уй-ю-юй...

Comment: @Дерзкий, *Краснополянский*. Если прилагательное образовано от словосочетания, то пишется слитно, если от двух самостоятельных слов - через дефис. Северо-западная - это северная и западная, значит через дефис, а южноамериканская - не южная и американская, следовательно слитно.

Comment: Пожалуйста, переведите на английский язык следующее: "А южноамериканская - не южная и американская."

Comment: Марк Из, Вы пересказываете кем-то придуманные правила, они не являются фундаментальными законами. Северо-западный ветер или северозападный - никакой разницы НЕТ.

Comment: @Дерзкий, согласен, написание так или иначе - это всего лишь условность, так что причин менять шило на мыло, тем более нет.

Comment: Все изменения в жизни подготавливаются постепенно. Потом р-р-раз! - и ты живешь в совсем другом мире. Такое происходит через каждые 36 лет)))

Comment: Знаю я эти истории про обмен "шила" на "мыло". Например, вы нам никчёмный жёлтый песочек, а мы вам зеркальца и топорики.

Answer (score 4):

Противоречит. Свойству любого языка. Это свойство - **инертность** (или *консервативность*). Чтобы изменить существующее написание, нужна гораздо более сильная причина, чем ваше желание провести эксперимент.

Answer (score 1):

По законам Рф, название города, определяют его жители, а не РГО, РАН, ФРИК, и пр.

Поэтому, например, Великий ***У***стюг останется таковым до тех пор, пока его так будут называть сами устюжане. Несмотря на то, что в остальных регионах его чаще называют Уст***ю***гом.

Comment: 1. Спасибо за предоставленные сведения о законах Рф.

2. Я ожидаю ответа на свой вопрос. Указанный ответ может иметь вид: "Дефисное" написание слова Санкт-Петербург "указывает на то, что два слова утрачивают самостоятельность, но не доходят до полного слияния в одно слово" СанктПетербург (цит. по участнице Людмиле).

Comment: >Я ожидаю ответа на свой вопрос. Указанный ответ может иметь вид: "Дефисное" написание слова Санкт-Петербург "указывает на то, что два слова утрачивают самостоятельность, но не доходят до полного слияния в одно слово"

Так и есть. А если ответ знаете, то зачем спрашивать?

Comment: Я не знаю, а предполагаю, каким может быть ответ участницы Людмилы, учитывая её предыдущие сообщения о свойствах русского языка.